# Is possible to create a foreign key without a primary key?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am creating two tables and I want to put a foreign key on the column customer_email knowing is not the primary key.

So is possible to create a foreign key without a primary key? And how I use DATE()?

Here is my table customer and order:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
customer_email VARCHAR(225)
customer_name VARCHAR(225)
customer_last_name VARCHAR(225)
);

CREATE TABLE order(
order_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
customer_email  VARCHAR(225) REFERENCES customer(customer_email)
product_1 DECIMAL(10,2)
product_2 DECIMAL(10,2)
product_3 DECIMAL(10,2)
product_4 DECIAML(10,2)
product_5 DECIAML(10,2)
order_date DATE()
);
```

Comment: `date()` is a function, but you need to define a column with a data type: `order_date date`

Comment: Note that your `order` table is not normalized, you should have an additional table that stores the products included in a single order, read up on normalization (Btw: `order` is a **really** bad name for a table, as `order` is a reserved keyword, you will have to use double quotes, `"order"` to use it).

Comment: Yeah...the code you posted here won't even compile, and please don't use `order` to name your tables and columns.

Comment: I know the order is a bad name but that's what came to mind....  is it possible for the date to be entered automatically, so enter the date of the day? because if I do select now (), give me the date today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres' [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/ddl-constraints.html) for the creation of foreign keys addresses your question:

> Finally, we should mention that a foreign key **must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint**. If the foreign key references a unique constraint, there are some additional possibilities regarding how null values are matched.

So, you certainly can create a foreign key in the `order` table which references `customer_email` in the `customer` table, but there would have to be a unique constraint on the email field.  So, the following definition for the `customer` table should work:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    customer_email VARCHAR(225),
    customer_name VARCHAR(225),
    customer_last_name VARCHAR(225),
    CONSTRAINT email_unique UNIQUE (customer_email)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. And I can put DATE() on table order?

Comment: @Bruno See the comment by the Horse under your original question.

Comment: Thank you, I had not even noticed